# Make boot partition using GParted in Boot-Repair

Tags: kernel, gparted, boot-repair

How do I create a BIOS boot partition with GParted? I am using Boot-Repair.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be able to right-click on the partition you want to set as bootable and click "Manage Flags", and then check the box for the boot flag.

If you are using `parted`, you can `print` for the list of partitions, and then `set 1 boot on` to enable the boot flag for the first partition.  If your drive uses a GPT partition table, you'll want to create a bios_grub partition instead using `set 1 bios_grub on`.