# can't boot by default on ubuntu installed on external drive

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I have installed ubuntu on a external drive on a ssd connected with usb and **I don't have an efi partition.**

I am in efi mode and **I have disable secure boot** and **I have set as first option to boot from usb**. But my pc doesn't boot from external drive (installed with ubuntu) and it boots to windows (internal ssd) directly.

If I abort the boot pressing ESC and then change boot option (with F9), I go to **windows boot manager and from there I can select ubuntu**.

But what could the easiest way to make my pc boots by default on ubuntu and not have to press ESC and then F9 to manually select ubuntu?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Do you want the computer to always try to boot into Ubuntu (easier)? Or only when then USB drive with Ubuntu is connected (more difficult)?

Comment: I don't have problem to boot always into UBUNTU.

Comment: Can you select the SSD you want to first boot from your BIOS menu?

Comment: on boot options I can't view my external disk. I can set only usb entry as first option on boot order

Comment: Some computers have another options about select for SSD.

Comment: Some computers have other options about selecting for SSD. It's not on the same where with selecting USB. Can you check somewhere else on your boot menu? Like 'Harddisk options'... You should select which harddisk booting...

Comment: i don't see a such option. even if I unplug external ssd, I can view ubuntu as an option to boot there pressing F9. but how I could make this option default?

Comment: Please tell us what computer it is (brand name and model)! Someone who has the same model or a similar one might be able to help you manage the UEFI-BIOS menu system.

Comment: When booted into Ubuntu, can you see (can Ubuntu see) the internal drive and the partition with Windows (NTFS file system)? If not please turn off Fast Startup in Windows. It means that a kind of semi-hibernation is turned off, and the file systems of Windows can be seen by Ubuntu, and Ubuntu should be able to make the internal drive 'dual bootable' (with a grub menu to select between Ubuntu and Windows, where Ubuntu get highest priority).

Comment: yep I can see ntfs file system. What should I do? it's an hp laptop 4-5 years ago.

Comment: When booted into Ubuntu, you can see the NTFS file system (of Windows). Please check if Ubuntu mounts it read-write or if it is read-only. If read-only you can *probably* fix it after you turn off Fast Startup in Windows. Then it should be possible for Ubuntu's installer to add a boot structure into the internal drive, so that Ubuntu will be one of the boot options (even the first option) by default. On the other hand, many people are happy to boot into the operating system in a USB drive via F9 and a temporary menu. (I have an old HP for testing Ubuntu, and it is OK for me to boot that way.)

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't used it yet, I suggest you use the Gparted tool.
You can use it to select the boot disk.

How to install the Gparted tool is explained in this video.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vlVXPtJ20hA

Here is how to change the boot disk on a similar question about Gparted.
[Make boot partition using GParted in Boot-Repair](https://askubuntu.com/questions/473641/make-boot-partition-using-gparted-in-boot-repair)

Good luck to you:)